# WeekOfYear overflowing to 1 in 53rd week in gregorian calendar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nscalendar

The issue I have is quite clear. This year, the 28th to 31st of december 2014 fall to 53rd week of 2014.
For some reason, NSCalendar is generating the wrong value when I extract the components from the date.
Why? Am I missing something?

```
NSDateComponents *mockTodayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
mockTodayComponents.day = 27;
mockTodayComponents.month = 12;
mockTodayComponents.year = 2014;

NSDate *mockToday  = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:mockTodayComponents];

/**************************/

NSDateComponents *weekOfYearComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                               fromDate:mockToday];
```

I get this

```
<NSDateComponents: 0xae7aba0>
    Calendar Year: 2014
    Week of Year: 1
```

Printing the calendar gives me

```
(lldb) po calendar.timeZone
Europe/London (GMT+1) offset 3600 (Daylight)

(lldb) po calendar.calendarIdentifier
gregorian
```

Comment: I updated the answer to be sure. It is.

Comment: It's a bit strange because the week clearly spans through 2014/2015 but I should either get week 53 of 2014 or week 1 of 2015. But week 1 of 2014 is obviously not correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that no one understands how the "week of year" stuff works.  And I believe you need to explicitly set the start of the year in your calendar object to get things to start as you wish.

Comment: You should be using `NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit` to get the year consistent with `WeekOfYear`.

Comment: (Look at the settings of `firstWeekday` and `minimumDaysInFirstWeek`.)

Comment: Using "NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear" instead of "NSCalendarUnitYear" fixed the issue an brought back consistency. Thank you @HotLicks.