# Wrong Year and weekOfYear in Gregorian Calendar objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
+ (NSCalendar*)getGregorianCalendarInstance {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    return calendar;
}

+ (NSInteger)currentGregorianWeekOfYear:(NSDate*) date {
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [self getGregorianCalendarInstance];
    gregorianCalendar.firstWeekday = 2; // Monday = 2
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:date];
    NSUInteger weekOfYear = [components weekOfYear];
    return weekOfYear;
}

+ (NSInteger)currentGregorianYear:(NSDate*) date {
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [self getGregorianCalendarInstance];
    gregorianCalendar.firstWeekday = 2;
    [gregorianCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    gregorianCalendar.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorianCalendar components: NSCalendarUnitYear  fromDate:date];
    NSInteger year = [comps year];
    return year;
}
```

week number returns 52 instead of 1 in `currentGregorianWeekOfYear` function and year returns 2019 instead of 2020 in `currentGregorianYear` function for date = `2019-12-30 15:00:00 +0000`

Specific reason to use the Gregorian calendar is to display 1st January in the 1st week of the year. With the ISO calendar, 1st January will be indicated as the 52nd or 53rd week of the year.

I already checked multiple references but it does not solve my problem:

1. [WeekOfYear overflowing to 1 in 53rd week in gregorian calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913712/weekofyear-overflowing-to-1-in-53rd-week-in-gregorian-calendar)
2. [NSDateComponents weekOfYear returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249588/nsdatecomponents-weekofyear-returns-wrong-value)
3. [Swift: Gregorian Calendar and weeks/weekdays - inconsistent behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154491/swift-gregorian-calendar-and-weeks-weekdays-inconsistent-behavior)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @koen How to get the correct year (2020) and weekOfYear (1) in the Gregorian calendar if I pass date 2019-12-30 15:00:00 +0000?

Comment: First, you want to use NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear and the -yearForWeakOfYear method to get the year associated with the ISO week.  The -year method will always return the straight calendar year.  Unsure about the weekOfYear being off, though.

Comment: What is your minimumDaysInFirstWeek value ?

Comment: @CarlLindberg I did not set any minimumDaysInFirstWeek. What should I set it?

Comment: @CarlLindberg I changed the year from NSCalendarUnitYear to NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear. For date 27-12-2020, I should get a year (yearForWeekOfYear) 2020, but getting 2021 in the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: By that, I'm wondering if the Gregorian calendar decides the first week of the year is the one with January 1 in it, instead of January 4 like ISO.  There is an NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601 , maybe use that instead of Gregorian.  I'm not sure if there is a way to affect the Gregorian interpretation, but minimumDaysInFirstWeek might be the one -- try setting that to 4 and see if that works.  If it's 1, that may explain the behavior you're seeing.